# Integration testing using spring data persistance with SpringRunner and JUnit - dummy data differ for each test

Tags: java, junit, spring-data-jpa

I am not sure if the title is descriptive enough. I am trying to insert dummy data to my database for testing purposes and I thought I should check that the dummy data has been persisted as expected. To my surprise a particular record was not persisting, so I tried to to find what is wrong with that record. In the end I realized that there is nothing wrong with that particular record.

Bellow you can see the that there are 4 tests asserting exactly the same thing. 1 of them is failing 3 are passing...
[image]

[image]

I think I am missing something fundamental here. Bellow is the test code

```
package testingSpring.rentals.service;

import testingSpring.affiliates.Affiliate;
import testingSpring.affiliates.AffiliateDbUtils;
import testingSpring.cars.Car;
import testingSpring.cars.CarDbUtils;
import testingSpring.clients.Client;
import testingSpring.clients.ClientDbUtils;
import testingSpring.rentals.db.*;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.AutoConfigureTestDatabase;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import java.util.Date;

import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.core.IsEqual.equalTo;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ComponentScan({
        "testingSpring.cars",
        "testingSpring.rentals.db",
        "testingSpring.clients",
        "testingSpring.rentals.service",
        "testingSpring.affiliates"
})
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
public class RentalServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private RentalRepository rentalRepository;

    @Autowired
    private CarDbUtils carDbUtils;

    @Autowired
    private RentalDbUtils rentalDbUtils;

    @Autowired
    private ClientDbUtils clientDbUtils;

    @Autowired
    private RentalService rentalService;

    @Autowired
    private AffiliateDbUtils affiliateDbUtils;

    @Before
    public void setup(){
        addDummyData();
    }



    @Test
    public void dummyDataIsPersisted(){
        assertThat(carDbUtils.count(), equalTo(5L));
        assertThat(clientDbUtils.count(), equalTo(1L));
        assertThat(affiliateDbUtils.count(), equalTo(1L));
        assertThat(rentalDbUtils.count(), equalTo(6L));

    }

    @Test
    public void letsCheckAgainJustForFun(){
        assertThat(carDbUtils.count(), equalTo(5L));
        assertThat(clientDbUtils.count(), equalTo(1L));
        assertThat(affiliateDbUtils.count(), equalTo(1L));
        assertThat(rentalDbUtils.count(), equalTo(6L));
    }
    @Test
    public void letsCheckAgainJustForFun2(){
        assertThat(carDbUtils.count(), equalTo(5L));
        assertThat(clientDbUtils.count(), equalTo(1L));
        assertThat(affiliateDbUtils.count(), equalTo(1L));
        assertThat(rentalDbUtils.count(), equalTo(6L));
    }
    @Test
    public void letsCheckAgainJustForFun3(){
        assertThat(carDbUtils.count(), equalTo(5L));
        assertThat(clientDbUtils.count(), equalTo(1L));
        assertThat(affiliateDbUtils.count(), equalTo(1L));
        assertThat(rentalDbUtils.count(), equalTo(6L));
    }

    private void addDummyData(){

        Car car1 = new Car("1plate1", "datsun", "A", "2000", "manual", "4x4", "green");
        Car car2 = new Car("2plate2", "datsuna", "b", "2000", "manual", "4x4", "yellow");
        Car car3 = new Car("3plate3", "datsuno", "c", "2000", "manual", "4x4", "black");
        Car car4 = new Car("4plate4", "datsuni", "v", "2000", "manual", "4x4", "white");
        Car car5 = new Car("5plate5", "datsunu", "a", "2000", "manual", "4x4", "red");
        carDbUtils.addCar(car1);
        carDbUtils.addCar(car2);
        carDbUtils.addCar(car3);
        carDbUtils.addCar(car4);
        carDbUtils.addCar(car5);


        Client client0 = new Client(0L,"kakakias","trois", "licencenu3","GH92312312",1996,"09801983123","putanga3@grail.com","UK","40 falsefall way");
        clientDbUtils.addClient(client0);

        Affiliate affiliate = new Affiliate("Klasikos Malakas", 0.25F, "4234234");
        affiliateDbUtils.addAffiliate(affiliate);

        Rental rental1 = new Rental(1L, car2,client0, affiliate, "aerobromio", "aerobromio", new Date(2018, 8, 10,12,0), new Date(2018,8,15,11,0), 150L,"gamistronas in","afroditi", PaymentType.CASH, RemainingPetrol.R1_2, "owefowekokfwek1", "no");
        Rental rental3 = new Rental(2L, car3,client0, affiliate, "aerobromio", "aerobromio", new Date(2018, 8, 11,12,0), new Date(2018,8,5,11,0), 150L,"gamistronas in","afroditi", PaymentType.CASH, RemainingPetrol.R1_2, "owefowekokfwek2", "no");
        Rental rental33 = new Rental(3L, car3,client0, affiliate, "aerobromio", "aerobromio", new Date(2018, 8, 20,12,0), new Date(2018,8,30,11,0), 150L,"gamistronas in","afroditi", PaymentType.CASH, RemainingPetrol.R1_2, "owefowekokfwek3", "no");
        Rental rental4 = new Rental(4L, car4,client0, affiliate, "aerobromio", "aerobromio", new Date(2018, 8, 21,12,0), new Date(2018,8,30,11,0), 150L,"gamistronas in","afroditi", PaymentType.CASH, RemainingPetrol.R1_2, "owefowekokfwek4", "no");
        Rental rental5 = new Rental(5L, car5,client0, affiliate, "aerobromio", "aerobromio", new Date(2018, 8, 15,12,0), new Date(2018,8,25,11,0), 150L,"gamistronas in","afroditi", PaymentType.CASH, RemainingPetrol.R1_2, "owefowekokfwek8", "no");
        Rental rental = new Rental(6L, car1,client0, affiliate, "aerobromio", "aerobromio", new Date(2018, 8, 1,12,0), new Date(2018,8,10,11,0), 150L,"gamistronas in","afroditi", PaymentType.CASH, RemainingPetrol.R1_2, "owefoweko654kfwek", "no");
        rentalDbUtils.addRental(rental);
        rentalDbUtils.addRental(rental1);
        rentalDbUtils.addRental(rental3);
        rentalDbUtils.addRental(rental33);
        rentalDbUtils.addRental(rental4);
        rentalDbUtils.addRental(rental5);


    }

}
```

Bellow is the dependencies

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
        <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/de.svenkubiak/jBCrypt -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.svenkubiak</groupId>
        <artifactId>jBCrypt</artifactId>
        <version>0.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Please let me know if I need to include anything else to this description.

Thank you!

[EDIT]
I am using a workaround which can be consider as a hack, but for the time being it will let me proceed.
In Junit 4.11 and later you can specify the order a set of test will run by annotating the test class with:
`@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)`

so a an empty method `@Test public void AAA_WarmUp(){}`

will run first and then the others are green. 
I am still curious though, so if someone has a proper explanation of what's going on I will be grateful. Thanks
[/EDIT]

Comment: Add the code for adddummydata

Comment: Hi @gaurav , if you scroll down the first snipset of code you will be able to see the method. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Only thing that comes to my mind is to try to delay the first test using Thread.sleep. I think that there might be some delay between inserting data and reading them.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer Adam, I tried that but it didn't work. @Before method is being run before every single test and after each test the db is wiped out.  so does it make sense to work only for the first? unless the first test is "warming up" the db or the context or whatever.. I have no idea

Comment: @GiorgosLamprakis Have you also tried to run the problematic test individually? Also , i do not think that your database is erased after each test. Before serves global state for all tests. I would give a try to these annotations - BeforeMethod or Before and AfterMethod or After. Try to use these annotations. In before annotation, insert into database and in after annotation, clear the database. I know that his method is not performance-friendly but it could be curious which results would this provide.